# В чём разница между Thread.Sleep(0) и Thread.Sleep(1) для многоядерных процессоров с Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

Использую библиотеку System.Threading в .NET Standard. Какое поведение ожидать от многопоточной программы, где в бесконечных циклах внутри каждого потока даётся одна из этих инструкций?

Comment: [Документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) Вы, наверное, читали. Что именно из нее непонятно?

Comment: Я помимо документации ещё и статьи читаю.

Comment: Замечательно, я и не сомневался! Тогда стоит написать в вопросе, что именно из прочитанного неясно. Хотя бы чтобы отвечающие не копировали то, что уже написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют такие сценарии выполнения программы, когда требуется, чтобы поток выполнения (Thread) приостановился, давая другим потокам возможность выполнять свой функционал. Это можно осуществить при помощи статического метода `Sleep` класса `Thread`:

```
public static void Sleep(int timeOut)
public static void Sleep(TimeSpan timeOut)
```

Аргумент `timeout` позволяет нам указывать, какой период времени поток должен быть неактивен. В этот период не будут тратиться ресурсы процессора на обслуживание потока.
А самое полезное для системы иметь возможность дать другим потокам период времени для выполнения собственных задач.Этого можно добиться передав в метод `Sleep` значение `0`. При этом система остановит поток и осуществит планирование выполнения другого потока. Но если на текущий момент остановленный поток будет единственным имеющий наивысший приобретет,то система опять поставит его на выполнение.Если же нужно остановить поток,так чтобы могли выполниться потоки с низким приоритетом, передайте в метод `Sleep` значение `1`.Тогда поток будет переведен в режим ожидания и остальные потоки получат шанс на выполнение.
[Thread.Sleep(0) и Thread.Sleep(1)](http://it-proposition.blogspot.am/2012/04/threadsleep0-threadsleep1.html)